# Component doesn't re-render after I set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a mini project in react, it is a BMI tracker, the user enters his weight and height, then the program calculates the BMI and whenever the application receives data (height and weight) from the user it then represents the result and the date at which the user entered that data in a graph. For that, I made three components, the first is the `InputContainer` component inside of which the calculations are performed.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Graph from '../Graph/Graph';
import Logs from '../Logs/logs';
import './InputContainer.scss';
let date;
let currentDate;
let dates = []
let bmiResults = []
let dataLog = [];
export default function InputContainer() {
    const [result, setBmiResult] = useState('');
    const [height, setHeight] = useState('');
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState('');
    const [bmiAxis,setBmiAxis] = useState('');
    const [dateAxis,setDateAxis] = useState('');
    const calculateButton = useRef(null);
    const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        date = new Date();
        currentDate = `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getFullYear()}`
        calculateButton.current.disabled = isNaN(parseFloat(height) && parseFloat(weight)) ? true : false;
    }, [height, weight]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (firstUpdate.current) {
            firstUpdate.current = false;
            return
        }
        let dataLogElement = <div className="test">
                    <div className="bmi-and-date">
                        <p className="bmi">
                            BMI: {result}
                        </p>
                        <p className="date">
                            Date: {currentDate}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="height-and-weight">
                        <p className="height">
                            Height: {height}
                        </p>
                        <p className="weight">
                            weight: {weight}
                        </p>
                    </div>
            </div>;
        dataLog.push(dataLogElement);
        dates.push(currentDate);
        bmiResults.push(result);
        setBmiAxis(bmiResults);
        setDateAxis(dates);
    }, [result])

    const calculate = () => {
        let bmi = (parseFloat(weight) / parseFloat(height) ** 2).toFixed(2)
        setBmiResult(parseFloat(bmi))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='input-container'>
                <h1>BMI Tracker</h1>
                <div className="input">
                    <div className="height">
                        <h3>Enter Your Height in CM</h3>
                        <input type="number" onChange={(e) => {
                            setHeight(e.target.value)
                        }} value={height} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="weight">
                        <h3>Enter Your Weight in Kg</h3>
                        <input type="number" onChange={(e) => {
                            setWeight(e.target.value)
                        }} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button className='calculate' onClick={calculate} ref={calculateButton}>Calculate</button>
            </div>
            <Graph bmi={result} date={currentDate} dates={dateAxis} results={bmiAxis} />
            <Logs element = {dataLog}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

the second component is the `Graph` component which receives the user's data from props and then displays it in a graph:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import './Graph.scss'


export default function Graph(props) {
    const data = {
        labels: props.dates,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'BMI',
                data: props.results,
                fill: 'origin',
                backgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
                pointBackgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
                pointBorderColor: 'blue',
                pointRadius: '4'
            },
        ],
    };
    const options = {
        tension: 0.4,
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    color: 'white'
                },
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    color: 'white'
                },
            }

        }
    };
    return (
        <div className='graph-container'>
            <Line data={data} options={options} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then the third component which is the `Logs` component, it displays
the details of each user submission at the button of the page

```
import React from 'react'
import './logs.scss'
export default function Logs(props) {
    return (
        <div className='logs-container'>
            {props.element}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Once I start the app, I enter the weight and height then click the `calculate` button, the data gets plotted into the graph successfully and its corresponding details are logged at the bottom of the page, and this is exactly what I wanted, but the problem is that the data entered by the user gets displayed successfully only for the first entry, when I enter data a second time, calculations are done properly in the background and the results of the second entry are calculated, but nothing changes on the screen, and I can only see the results of the first entry, then once I start entering data for the third entry, I get the results of the first along with the second entry that I previously entered displayed on the screen, results only get displayed when I start entering data for the next entry and not immediately after clicking the `calculate` button.
Here Is an example of what I want to achieve:
[image]

And Here is a link of the repo if you want to test it in your machine:
https://github.com/Marouane328/Bmi-tracker

Comment: Some notes: (1) Don't put markup into state. (2) Don't use refs just to set attributes on buttons; just use the props. (3) The BMI result should be a computed value, not part of state, since it's not user-editable. (4) There should be no global `dates`/`bmiResults`/... variables; any changes to those will NOT be tracked by anything and nothing will rerender.

Comment: @AKX thanks for the notes, you said that I shouldn't use refs just to set attributes on buttons, what can I do instead? And I set the BMI result to as part of state because only when the result the is computed the state is updated, therefore the re-render

Comment: `<button disabled={isNaN(parseFloat(height) && parseFloat(weight))} />`

Comment: And you don't need to put the BMI in state, since height and weight are already in state. If the height and weight change, the component rerenders, and you can compute the BMI in-component based on those.

Comment: @AKX Thanks, i didn't pay attention to that, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In Graph, can you consider converting `const data` and `const options` to states and use useEffect to assign the props values to the states giving props has dependency for useEffect.

try this it worked in your repo at codesandbox(https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-hofstadter-onso9):

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    labels: props.dates,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'BMI',
            data: props.results,
            fill: 'origin',
            backgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
            pointBorderColor: 'blue',
            pointRadius: '4'
        },
    ],
});
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState({
    tension: 0.4,
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                color: 'white'
            },
            beginAtZero: true
        },
        x: {
            ticks: {
                color: 'white'
            },
        }

    }
});

React.useEffect(
    ()=>{
        setData({
            labels: props.dates,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'BMI',
                    data: props.results,
                    fill: 'origin',
                    backgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#16a5e1',
                    pointBorderColor: 'blue',
                    pointRadius: '4'
                },
            ],
        });
        setOptions({
            tension: 0.4,
            scales: {
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                x: {
                    ticks: {
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                }
    
            }
        });
    },[props]
)
```

Comment: This should use `useMemo` instead.

Comment: @Vishwa Why did you put the props on the dependency array in the Graph component?

Comment: so whenever there is a change in props, the useEffect gets executed and the latest values get attached to your state hooks. Did the solution work for you?